# Is using a Monte Carlo simulation sufficient for predicting probabilities that a stock will hit a certain price by a certain date?

Tags: monte-carlo

Forgive my ignorance about my question. I understand a Monte Carlo simulation to basically be `n` times that the truth is checked in some historic data set. For stock prices, if I buy some symbol at say \$100 and I want to predict the probability that the price will reach \$105 within 30 days.

Can I use a MC simulation to look at historic prices and see what the percent gain / loss was over a 30 day period from random starting points and use that to build my probability curve?

Is that too naive or will that yield decent results?

Comment: IMO What you describe in the first part simply amounts to assimilating the probability of occurrence of an event to its historical count. This has *nothing to do with Monte Carlo* which necessitates sampling out of a distribution.

Comment: If you are willing to estimate or guess two parameters: the *drift* and the *variance* then you can use the lognormal distribution (which is analytically tractable) to estimate the future range of a stock with a given confidence threshold. See GBM (Geometric Brownian Motion) for more information.